# query to django model to compare daily sale over previous day (compare two row of database model)

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-annotate

I have a django model that is "DailyReport" of the companies sale I want to find out company sale change over the previous day.
the model that i define is like that:

```
class DailyReport(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sale = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
```

How can i figure out this issue to add new column for every report that represent change rate over the previous day

[image: the tables that i wanna to show in view]

Comment: Can we assume that we don't have duplicate dates for same company?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`Lag`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#lag) window function to annotate each row with the previous sale amount for that company.

Then use another annotation to calculate the difference between the current and previous sale

```
from django.db.models import Window, F
from django.db.models.functions import Lag

DailyReport.objects.annotate(
    prev_val=Window(
        expression=Lag('sale', default=0),
        partition_by=['company'],
        order_by=F('date').asc(),
    )
).annotate(
    diff=F('sale') - F('prev_val')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can have only one record of a company for each day, you can create a model property:

```
@property
def previous_day_sale(self):
  date = self.date 
  dr = DailyReport.objects.filter(company=self.company, date=date-timedelta(days=1)
  if dr:
    return dr.first().sale - self.sale
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to override the save method, but you will have to cover all edge cases.

```py
class DailyReport(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    sale = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
    sale_over_previous_day = models.IntegerField()
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        previous_day_sale_object = DailyReport.objects.filter(company=self.company, date=date-timedelta(days=1))
        if previous_day_sale_object:
            previous_day_sale = previous_day_sale_object[0].sale
        else:
            previous_day_sale = 0
        self.sale_over_previous_day = self.sale - previous_day_sale
        super(DailyReport, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Good but the problem is that data base was filled with data so save method will not work in this situation

Comment: @kazemqanati modify the model and update it if you have less data using save method.
If you don't want it in database, you can use [@antpngl92's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73162599/13779320)